# Отловить ошибки в php

Tags: php

Когда возникает **ошибка**, ее видно в браузере **одной** строкой.

> `Fatal error: MySQL error :: Query was empty
>   in /home/p/qwerty/public_html/Database.class.php on line 82`

Но помню на каком-то сайте, парень писал код, что у него выводилась ошибка и также список файлов и номера строк, в которых она появилась, то есть все по порядку, это вроде стека что-то. Очень удобно, может подскажет кто, как реализуется или какой-то класс для этого?

Пример:

> `Fatal error: MySQL error :: Query was empty
>   in /home/p/qwerty/public_html/Database.class.php on line 82
>   in файл2 on line 56
>   in файл3 on line 456
>   in .............. on line 73`

Кстати, может подскажете, что за ошибка, Query was empty, работало все ок до недавнего времени, а сейчас такая ошибка... и понять не могу.

Comment: Вообще если хочешь чтоб всё было красиво, как вариант можно сделать так:
Создай свой обработчик ошибок - класс-наследник стандартного класса Exception. В нём реализовано всё из того, что Вы перечислили. И как сказал @Asen просто "прослушивать" код на исключения try-catch'ем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для установки своих обработчиков используй

[set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php)

[set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php)

Comment: Есть ещё http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trigger-error.php, но ей не пользовался никогда. первых 2х хватает на все случаи жизни.

Comment: это я нашел, ок, но наверно есть библиотеки?
я вот нашел PHP_Exceptionizer
но что то он кривовато выводит, но спас мне жизнь, разобрался с этой ошибкой за минуту, но хотелось бы красивый вывод, без кракозябр и какох то вопросиков

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать и стандартную конструкцию `try->throw->catch`